# Access instance variable by using instance name

Tags: python, instance-variables

I have a class like this:

```
Class PropertyExpr:
    def __init__(self, value, expr):
        self.value = value
        self.expr = expr
```

Let's say I initialize the class like this:

```
prop1 = PropertyExpr(5, "test")
```

I understand that if I want to get access to `value` or `expr` I would call `prop1.value` or `prop1.expr`.

However, I want to make it so that whenever I call `prop1`, it will automatically return `prop1.value`. `prop1.expr` would still get access to the `expr` variable

Since `value` can be any datatype, I don't think using `__str__` would work.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: This was my current approach, but it only work for int, and I need to extend this so that it work for other data type as well, such as list:

```
class PropertyExpr(int):

    def __new__(self, value: int, expr: Optional[str]=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return int.__new__(self, value, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, value: int, expr: Optional[str]=None, *args, **kwargs):
        int.__init__(value, *args, **kwargs)
        if expr is None:
            self.expr = str(value)
        else:
            self.expr = expr
```

So when I create an instance:

```
prop1 = PropertyExpr(5, "test")
```

So when I use `prop1`, it would return 5, and `prop1.expr = "test"`.

Comment: If you did that, how would you access `prop1.expr`? Since `prop1` turns into `prop1.value`, that's equivalent to `prop1.value.expr`

Comment: Note, `__str__` **does not get called** when you use just `prop1`... You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how that works. In any case, what you are asking for isn't possible in Python, and shouldn't ever be necessary (or I would argue, useful)

Comment: `__str__` gets called if you write something like `print(prop1)`. You certainly could use that method to make this do what you want there, but not for more general references to `prop1`.

Comment: E.g. it wouldn't work for `print(prop1 + 1)`, which would complain about trying to concatenate a string with an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "call" you actually mean call and not just "access" you can simply implement a `__call__` method:

```
class PropertyExpr:
    def __init__(self, value, expr):
        self.value = value
        self.expr = expr

    def __call__(self):
        return self.value

prop1 = PropertyExpr(5, "test")

val = prop1()
print(val)
```

Output:

```
5
```

In that case, the result of calling `prop1()` can be really anything.

Other than that, what you want is not possible. You could override the `__new__` method, but that will also change the type of what you're creating. So if you're returning `5` your object will be `5`, but it will also be an `int` and no longer an instance of `PropertyExpr` and all your additional attributes will be lost:

```
class PropertyExpr():
    def __new__(cls, value, expr):
        return value

    def __init__(self, value, expr):
        self.value = value
        self.expr = expr

prop1 = PropertyExpr(5, "test")

print(prop1, type(prop1))
try:
    print(prop1.expr)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
5 <class 'int'>
'int' object has no attribute 'expr'
```

---

After some trying around, I've figured out a way to dynamically change the type of the constructor, however I would advise against actually using this:

```
class PropertyExpr:
    def __new__(cls, tp, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return type("FakeType", (tp,), kwargs)(value)

prop1 = PropertyExpr(int, 5, expr="expr int")
print(prop1, " -> ", prop1.expr)

prop2 = PropertyExpr(list, "5", expr="expr list")
print(prop2, " -> ", prop2.expr)

prop3 = PropertyExpr(str, "abc", expr="expr string")
print(prop3, " -> ", prop3.expr)
```

Output:

```
5  ->  expr int     
['5']  ->  expr list
abc  ->  expr string
```

You can pass the type you wish to sub-class as the first parameter, the second parameter should be a value accepted by the type's contructor and then you can pass in arbitrary kwargs that will be added as attributes to the created object.

---

> is there a way to make is so that type(prop1) would still be PropertyExpr? Edit: for example, if we can do isinstance(prop1, PropertyExpr) = True then everything would be perfect

I could not get that to work (that does not mean that others cannot), but I managed to make it work with multi inheritance, so you can use `isinstance(prop1, PropertyExprMixin)`:

```
class PropertyExprMixin:
    pass

class PropertyExpr:
    def __new__(cls, tp, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return type("PropertyExprMixin", (tp,PropertyExprMixin), kwargs)(value)

prop1 = PropertyExpr(int, 5, expr="expr int")
print(prop1, " -> ", prop1.expr, type(prop1), isinstance(prop1, int), isinstance(prop1, PropertyExprMixin))

prop2 = PropertyExpr(list, "5", expr="expr list")
print(prop2, " -> ", prop2.expr, type(prop2), isinstance(prop2, list), isinstance(prop2, PropertyExprMixin))

prop3 = PropertyExpr(str, "abc", expr="expr string")
print(prop3, " -> ", prop3.expr, type(prop3), isinstance(prop3, str), isinstance(prop3, PropertyExprMixin))
```

Output:

```
5  ->  expr int <class '__main__.PropertyExprMixin'> True True     
['5']  ->  expr list <class '__main__.PropertyExprMixin'> True True
abc  ->  expr string <class '__main__.PropertyExprMixin'> True True
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he means, since he also wrote **I would call prop1.value or prop1.expr**. He's using "call" to mean "write".

Comment: they almost certainly mean "just access" unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think call() is what I'm looking for. I edited the post and your second approach looks somewhat similar to what I was using. I subclass the int class but that approach only work for int

Comment: @Kenji Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Mike very interesting, do you might explain why I should not use the third approach?

Comment: Because it not just creates a new object, it also creates a new type every time. It's also against the principal of least astonishment: all objects will be of the dynamic type "FakeType", however the objects themself are of a subclass of whatever you pass in as type, so type checks will probably not work correctly. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Update: using ``isinstance`` to check for the base type seems to work, even after creating different objects of different types ... so at least this might not be an issue after all.

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to what I need, and probably will be the answer I'll go with.
If I do `print(type(prop1))`, I would get `<class '__main__.FakeType'>`, is there a way to make is so that `type(prop1)` would still be PropertyExpr?

Edit: for example, if we can do `isinstance(prop1, PropertyExpr) = True` then everything would be perfect

Comment: @Kenji Please have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
class PropertyExpr(int):

    def __new__(cls, value, expr):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, value)
        obj.expr = expr
        return obj
 
var = PropertyExpr(5, "test")
print(var)
print(var.expr)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 so.py 
5
test
```

Comment: This is almost the same way as my current approach, but this only work if value is int. I need to have support for other types as well, such as list.

Comment: You cannot create a reusable class as the attribute can only be added at creation time from what I’ve tried.